# Call an executable of OCaml or C from VBA code

Tags: c, vba, excel, ocaml, executable

Under `Ubuntu` I have coded a very simple `ml.ml` in OCaml:

```
let () = print_string "hello world, in OCaml\n"
```

And a simple `c.c`in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
  printf("hello world, in C\n");
  return 0; }
```

Then I compiled it by `ocamlc -o mlexe.exe ml.ml` and `gcc -o cexe.exe c.c`. Launching `mlexe.exe` or `cexe.exe` under a terminal of `Ubuntu` does return the string.

Now I would like to call it from a VBA code. I launch the Windows, open a Microsoft Excel file, and the VBA editor, and put:

```
Sub run()
    Dim ProcID As Integer
    ProcID = Shell("C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe", 1)

    Dim Result As Variant
    Result = Shell("C:\test\cexe.exe",1)
    'Result = Shell("C:\test\mlexe.exe",1)
    'Result = Shell("C:\test\cexe.exe")
    'Result = Shell("C:\test\mlexe.exe")
End Sub
```

I would expect `Result` get the string `hello world...` (or an exit code in a less good case), running the macro does launch the calculator, but gives me an error `Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument`, for the other 4 `Shell` with my own executables.

The aim is just to call an executable compiled by myself in another language from VBA code.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What happens if you use the native compiler `ocamlopt` instead of the bytecode compiler `ocamlc` to produce the program? I think it might be simpler then. Otherwise, since `hello.exe` is actually a bytecode file, you can try to run `ocamlrun.exe hello.exe`

Comment: Does the ocaml program really *return* the string or just *print* it? I suppose the latter.

Comment: @PascalCuoq : I have tried `ocamlopt`, and got same error. I tried `Result = Shell("""ocamlrun.exe"" C:\test\hello.exe")`, and it returns `File not found`.

Comment: @phimuemue : you are right, but I have tried `let () = "hello world"`, the compilation says `Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type unit`, is it possible to let an executable return something other than unit?

Comment: Not sure, but I think the return value is usually an integer. Maybe OCaml's `exit` function helps out...

Comment: @phimuemue : `let () = 123` gives also a type conflict error...

Comment: Does it work if you write in C++ (for instance) a program that prints "Hello world"?

Comment: If you want your program to return an exit code other than 0, write `let () = exit 42`. But exit codes are used to report normal termination (code 0) or error (anything other than 0), rather than to transmit data to other programs. One usual way to transmit data is indeed to print to standard output.

Comment: @jrouquie : I have totally amended OP, it still does not work.

Comment: Just a trivial check: you did recompile your OCaml or C files under Windows, to get Windows binaries instead of Linux binaries, right? (I'm asking because the convention for naming executables under Linux is not to use the .exe extension). If you get the same behavior with C and OCaml, I obviously suspect the problem is not with the language.

Comment: Also, try `ocamlc -custom -o ml-hello-world ml.ml` to get a standalone binary, just in case Excel does not find ocamlrun.exe .

Comment: @jrouquie : I compiled the .exe file under Ubuntu by the commands in the OP, I did NOT recompile OCaml or C files under Windows, how to do that? I have tried `ocamlc -custom -o ml-hello-world ml.ml`, still it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers in the comments. So the problems seems to be that you have an executable compiled under Ubuntu, which is called under Windows.
Windows executables and Linux executables are different and cannot be used in lieu of the other.

The easiest solution to your problem is to install a compiler under Windows, compile your code with it, and thus get a Windows binary.
For OCaml, see for instance http://protz.github.com/ocaml-installer/ .

Another way would be to *cross compile*, i.e. compiling under Linux but explicitely asking the compiler to generate a Windows executable. This is harder.

Comment: Thank you very much... I have installed it. Within `cygwin`, I can do `ocamlc -o mlexe.exe ml.ml`, and this `mlexe.exe` can be called from VBA. I am not sure how complicated compilation (with `makefile`) will work within `cygwin`, but it is already a first step...